# How can I reformat the following text using regular expressions in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

-- Original text:

```
update t1 set a1=1,b2=2 where c1=3;update t2 set a2=1 where c2=3;update t3 set c3=3;

update t4 set a4=1,
b4=2 where c4=3;

update t5 set 
a5=1,
b5=2 
where c5=3;

update t6 
set 
a6=1
where 
c6=3;
```

--  Desired text:

```
select * from t1 where c1=3;
select * from t2 where c2=3;
select * from t3 ;
select * from t4 where c4=3;
select * from t5 where c5=3;
select * from t6 where c6=3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the regular expression mode on:

Find: `update\s+(\S+)\s+set.*?((where)\s+(.*?))?;\s*`
Replace: `select * from $1 $3 $4;\n`
Check option: ☑ `.` matches newline

Make sure you have a recent version of Notepad++

Comment: Thanks.
the output is  :
update t1 set a1=1,b2=2 where c1=3;
update t2 set a2=1 where c2=3;
update t3 set c3=3;    

but I want :
update t1 where c1=3;
update t2 where c2=3;
update t3 where c3=3;

my notepad version is 6.9.2

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my request clearly yearterday, I  want to change the unformatted update statement into select , could you please see it again, Many Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain 
Check option: . finds \n and \r


update t1 set a1=1,b2=2 where c1=3;update t2 set a2=1 where c2=3;update t3 set c3=3;
-- successful

update t4 set a4=1,
b4=2 where c4=3;

update t5 set 
a5=1,
b5=2 
where c5=3;

update t6 
set 
a6=1
where 
c6=3;
--failed

Comment: There is a checkbox in the search dialog, which you need to check for the regular expression to work. Do you see it? It is just next to the "regular expression" option. I don't have the English version, so it might be called differently, like ". matches newlines"

Comment: Amazing!Thank you for helping me!